# YII: GridView: What's the right way to add date filter?

Tags: events, filter, gridview, yii

How I do it so far:

```php
GridView::widget([
    'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'my_date',
            'value' => function($data) { return $data->my_date ? DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $data->my_date)->format('d.m.Y') : false; },
            'filterInputOptions' => ['type' => 'date'],
        ],
    ]
])
```

I want to use the browser date picker, not a plugin. It works okay, but when I type in the date the onchange/onkeydown event submits the filter before I'm finishing entering. It seems it submits as soon as the date is valid.

Is there a way to set a minimum for valid dates for the filter row (not in rules)? Or can I just disable the event handler for this particular row? I tried with JS but it seems that Yii adds the events as soon as there is an input field. Even when I add it after loading or replace the existing field.